# How Guru decides his Shishya and chose for preachings?

Tags: scripture, gods, guru, vedic-gods, spirituality

This question is beyond what we all think as per my knowledge. The ultimate Guru, Shishya relationship was Vivekananda and Ramakrishna Paramahamsa as per the story i have read.

Ramakrishna Paramahamsa was also in search of his Shishya too and he just grabbed once Swami Vivekananda came to him and told he will show the god without any doubts. With the confidence in his eyes Swami Vivekananda became a devotee and rest is the history.

How and what exactly the Guru choses his Shishya? Are the guru relationships from yugas or 6th sense states that he will be the right or wrong spontaneously?

This platform has some experts and masters in a lot of readings and also mastered in many things in which i dono nothing infront of them. Would like to hear some of your honest answers that could enlight all of us here. Because finding Guru is also beyond Art and we find most fake lustful Gurus and Gold diggers now who are fit for nothing.

**Expectations of the answer:**

1. The answer to this question should help the one who are in search of
   his Guru.
2. Give a conclusion to stop finding if Guru only wants to
   find Shishya.
3. What could be the mindset of Guru and what qualities
   he prefers from Shishya.

Comment: What is wrong with the question to be closed? This is the platform to know what benefits users and get enlightened with Hindu culture as well. Simply coming here and clicking on close without any valid reasons are shame to themselves...

Comment: Only one close vote. So don't worry. It won't get closed eventually. Some users here are heavy close-voters and also down-voters like Swami Viswananda.

Comment: Real Guru is the Higher Self or God. https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/teachings/%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93/ What one seeks one attracts,basic law of attraction. Because in current Kaliyuga,age of ignorance, majority seek wealth or occult powers, not enlightenment or creator of existence, hence fake Gurus called babas with their cults are more popular worldwide. Therefore the need of science, modern education and reasoning to question blind spirituality of past.